# Why can't I use custom slugs for Parent and Children in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm trying to use custom slugs for Parent and Child models.

Models:

```
# models.py

class Parent(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField()

class Child(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
    order = models.IntegerField()
    slug = models.SlugField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['order', 'pk']

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = f"{parent.slug}/{self.order}"
        super(Text, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse("app:child-detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
```

The Child model will use its order and the Parent's slug in its slug.

I can get everything working with the default `<int:pk>` in the URLs but when I try to swap it to `<slug:slug>`, I get this error on both List and Detail views:

> Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name
> "app:child-detail". You may have failed to include the related model
> in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on
> this field.

When I try to call get_absolute_url() on a Child object (where the order is '1' and the parent's slug is 'parent-slug'), I get the following error:

> django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'child-detail' with
> keyword arguments '{'slug': 'parent-slug/1'}' not found. 2 pattern(s)
> tried:
> ['api/v1/child/(?P[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(?P\.[a-z0-9]+/?)$',
> 'api/v1/child/(?P[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$']

URLs:

```
# project urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("api/v1/", include("app.urls", namespace="app")),
    path("api-auth/", include("rest_framework.urls")),  # login for Browserable API
]

# app urls.py

from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns

app_name = "app"
urlpatterns = [
    path("children/", ChildList.as_view(), name="child-list"),
    path("child/<slug:slug>", ChildDetail.as_view(), name="child-detail"),
]

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

Views:

```
# app views.py

class ChildList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Child.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ChildSerializer
    lookup_field = "slug"

class ChilldDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Child.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ChildDetailSerializer
    lookup_field = "slug"
```

Serializers:

```
# app serializers.py

class ChildSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    url = HyperlinkedIdentityField(
        view_name="app:child-detail", lookup_field="slug"
    )

    class Meta:
        fields = ("url", "pk")
        model = Child
        # Commented out code below also doesn't work
        # lookup_field = "slug"
        # extra_kwargs = {"url": {"lookup_field": "slug"}}

class ChildDetailSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    url = HyperlinkedIdentityField(
        view_name="app:child-detail", lookup_field="slug"
    )

    class Meta:
        fields = ("url", "pk")
        model = Child
        # Commented out code below also doesn't work
        # lookup_field = "slug"
        # extra_kwargs = {"url": {"lookup_field": "slug"}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"{parent.slug}/{self.order}"` - this is not a [slug](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/glossary/#term-slug)

> Slug is a newspaper term. A slug is a short label for something, containing only letters, numbers, underscores or hyphens. They’re generally used in URLs.

Back or forward slash is not allowed in slug field. That's why `<slug:slug>` pattern does not accept it - value `parent/1` is not a valid slug.

Consider using [FilePathField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#filepathfield) or different separator (allowed for slugs) or use [slugify](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#slugify) function before saving anything into SlugField.

Comment: Thanks. However I'm receiving the same errors when I replace "/" with "-" for the SlugField so something else is going on.

Comment: Well, previously created records are in DB already, so update this field in DB for existing records.